# Finding $a$ so that the integral converges

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

So i want to find all $a$ for which this integral converges:
$$\int_0^{\infty}x^ae^{sgn(a)x}dx$$

So i know i should somehow look for an integral simmilar to this one:
$$\int_k^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$$, since it covnerges for $\alpha >1 $ and diverges for $0<\alpha \leq 1$

Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: For $-1<a<0$ the integral is $\Gamma(a+1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x \mapsto x^ae^{sgn(a)x}$ is continuous over $(0,\infty)$, potential issues of convergence are as $x \to 0^+$ and as $x \to \infty$.

As $x \to 0^+$, we have
$$
x^ae^{\text{sgn}(a)x}=x^a(1+O(x)) \sim x^a
$$ giving a convergent integral ($\varepsilon>0$)$\displaystyle \int_0^{\varepsilon}x^ae^{\text{sgn}(a)x}dx$ *iff* $a>-1$.

As $x \to \infty$, we need $a<0$ unless the integral ($M>0$) $\displaystyle \int_M^{\infty}x^ae^{\text{sgn}(a)x}dx$ diverges ($x^ae^{\text{sgn}(a)x}\ge x^ae^x)$:
$$
\int_M^{\infty}x^ae^{\text{sgn}(a)x}dx=\int_M^{\infty}x^ae^{-x}dx<\infty.
$$

The given integral is then convergent for $-1<a<0$.